# How to pass *encrypted* password in linux ssh command? is there a way to pass encrypted password?

Tags: linux, devops

I'm trying to execute the below command:

```
#sudo ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@serverip /var/scripts/test.sh
```

How can I use this command without ssh keys and with encrypted password in a script?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Comment: Neither of those posts address the question asked, which is a reasonable one. In fact I need to do exactly what has been asked (just haven't gotten onto it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use say a tool such as Ansible Vault (or equivalent) to encrypt the password, then feed it into the ssh command with sshpass.

You will end up with a master passphrase with such a setup of course.